# Rabbitmq mqtt broker uses a lot of memory

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

I am evaluating rabbitmq as mqtt broker and currently doing benchmark tests to check performance. Using benchmark tool https://github.com/takanorig/mqtt-bench I tried publishing 1 byte messages for 10000 clients. The memory consumption by rabbitmq for these numbers is 2gb and it's the same for 10000 subscriptions as well. Here are the consumption details provided by rabbitmq-diagnostics memory_breakdown

```
connection_other: 1.1373 gb (55.89%)
other_proc: 0.3519 gb (17.29%)
allocated_unused: 0.1351 gb (6.64%)
other_system: 0.0706 gb (3.47%)
quorum_ets: 0.0675 gb (3.32%)
plugins: 0.0555 gb (2.73%)
binary: 0.0482 gb (2.37%)
mgmt_db: 0.035 gb (1.72%)
```

This means that the broker server is taking 200KB per connection, which seems to me a big number, considering that we need to scale our system to 1million connections in future and then we would need to provide around 200gb for just rabbitmq.

I have tried playing with some settings in my conf file and docker command

```
mqtt.allow_anonymous=false
ssl_options.cacertfile=/certs/ca_certificate.pem
ssl_options.certfile=/certs/server_certificate.pem
ssl_options.keyfile=/certs/server_key.pem
ssl_options.verify=verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert=false
mqtt.listeners.ssl.default=8883
mqtt.listeners.tcp.default=1883
web_mqtt.ws_path = /mqtt
web_mqtt.tcp.port = 15675
collect_statistics_interval = 240000
management.rates_mode = none
mqtt.tcp_listen_options.sndbuf = 1000
mqtt.tcp_listen_options.recbuf = 2000
mqtt.tcp_listen_options.buffer = 1500
```

Below is the docker command where I've tried to reduce tcp_rmem and tcp_wmem size as well

```
docker run -d --rm -p 8883:8883 -p 1883:1883 -p 15675:15675 -p 15672:15672 -v /home/ubuntu/certs:/certs --sysctl net.core.somaxconn=32768 --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=4096 --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='1024 4096 500000' --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_wmem='1024 4096 500000' -e RABBITMQ_VM_MEMORY_HIGH_WATERMARK=0.9 -e RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="+P 2000000" -t probusdev/hes-rabbitmq:latest
```

Are there any other settings I can try to reduce the memory consumption?

---

Update: I used the same benchmark test against Emq broker and it took only 400mb for the same numbers. So is Rabbitmq mqtt more memory consuming then Emq?

Comment: A single data point is not enough to make an extrapolation. Have you tried with a different number of clients? Also things like the size of messages, retained flags and the QOS and message queuing.

Comment: I have also tried running the benchmark tool in parallel from 5 different machines. Same results